# Same accuracy in all epochs in GoogleNet neural network

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN0pE.jpg)I am getting same accuracy in all epochs of GoogleNet, this should not be the case, the network should learn in each epoch and therefore accuracy should vary in each epoch.
Please look at my code and help figure out how can I correct it. Decreasing the learning rate by 1/10 is not helping, could it be a problem with the way I am using the images data? I am importing the images one by one and during each image import I am first importing one image then resizing it, then converting it into float and dividing it by 255 and adding to an image list.

```
import keras
from keras.layers.core import Layer
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D,  \
    Dropout, Dense, Input, concatenate,      \
    GlobalAveragePooling2D, AveragePooling2D,\
    Flatten

import cv2 
import os
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

from keras.datasets import cifar10 
from keras import backend as K 
from keras.utils import np_utils

import math 

from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import optimizers
keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)

from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler


folder_train = 'D:/ResearchProject/data/siim-acr-pneumothorax/train'
folder_test = 'D:/ResearchProject/data/siim-acr-pneumothorax/test'
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            img = np.array(cv2.resize(img, (224,224)))
            img = img.astype('float32')
            img = img / 255.0
            images.append(img)
    return images
images_test = load_images_from_folder(folder_test)
images_train = load_images_from_folder(folder_train)

images_test = np.array(images_test)
print(type(images_test),images_test.shape)
images_train = np.array(images_train)
print(type(images_train),images_train.shape)

# read the labels of the images

path_test = 'D:/ResearchProject/data/siim-acr-pneumothorax/stage_1_test_images.csv'
label_test = pd.read_csv(path_test, usecols=[2], skiprows = 1,header = None)

path_train = 'D:/ResearchProject/data/siim-acr-pneumothorax/stage_1_train_images.csv'
label_train = pd.read_csv(path_train, usecols=[2], skiprows = 1,header = None)

Y_train, Y_valid = label_train, label_test
Y_train, Y_valid = np.array(Y_train), np.array(Y_valid)
print(Y_train.shape,type(Y_train), Y_valid.shape, type(Y_valid))


num_classes = 2
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_valid, num_classes)


print(images_train.shape, Y_train.shape, images_test.shape, Y_valid.shape)


# Inception module function
def inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1,
                     filters_3x3_reduce,
                     filters_3x3,
                     filters_5x5_reduce,
                     filters_5x5,
                     filters_pool_proj,
                     name=None):
    
    conv_1x1 = Conv2D(filters_1x1, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)
    
    conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filters_3x3_reduce, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)
    conv_3x3 = Conv2D(filters_3x3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_3x3)

    conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5_reduce, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(x)
    conv_5x5 = Conv2D(filters_5x5, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(conv_5x5)

    pool_proj = MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    pool_proj = Conv2D(filters_pool_proj, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(pool_proj)

    output = concatenate([conv_1x1, conv_3x3, conv_5x5, pool_proj], axis=3, name=name)
    
    return output



kernel_init = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()
bias_init = keras.initializers.Constant(value=0.2)


# defining layers of CNN
input_layer = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

x = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', name='conv_1_7x7/2', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(input_layer)
x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_1_3x3/2')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', name='conv_2a_3x3/1')(x)
x = Conv2D(192, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', name='conv_2b_3x3/1')(x)
x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_2_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=64,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                     filters_3x3=128,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                     filters_5x5=32,
                     filters_pool_proj=32,
                     name='inception_3a')

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=128,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                     filters_3x3=192,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                     filters_5x5=96,
                     filters_pool_proj=64,
                     name='inception_3b')

x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_3_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=192,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                     filters_3x3=208,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                     filters_5x5=48,
                     filters_pool_proj=64,
                     name='inception_4a')


x1 = AveragePooling2D((5, 5), strides=3)(x)
x1 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Flatten()(x1)
x1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Dropout(0.7)(x1)
x1 = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_1')(x1)

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=160,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=112,
                     filters_3x3=224,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=24,
                     filters_5x5=64,
                     filters_pool_proj=64,
                     name='inception_4b')

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=128,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                     filters_3x3=256,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=24,
                     filters_5x5=64,
                     filters_pool_proj=64,
                     name='inception_4c')

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=112,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=144,
                     filters_3x3=288,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                     filters_5x5=64,
                     filters_pool_proj=64,
                     name='inception_4d')


x2 = AveragePooling2D((5, 5), strides=3)(x)
x2 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = Flatten()(x2)
x2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = Dropout(0.7)(x2)
x2 = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_2')(x2)

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=256,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                     filters_3x3=320,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                     filters_5x5=128,
                     filters_pool_proj=128,
                     name='inception_4e')

x = MaxPool2D((3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), name='max_pool_4_3x3/2')(x)

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=256,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                     filters_3x3=320,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                     filters_5x5=128,
                     filters_pool_proj=128,
                     name='inception_5a')

x = inception_module(x,
                     filters_1x1=384,
                     filters_3x3_reduce=192,
                     filters_3x3=384,
                     filters_5x5_reduce=48,
                     filters_5x5=128,
                     filters_pool_proj=128,
                     name='inception_5b')

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool_5_3x3/1')(x)

x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)


model = Model(input_layer, [x, x1, x2], name='GoogleNet_Inception_v1')
model.summary()

epochs = 15
#initial_lrate = 0.01
initial_lrate = 0.001

def decay(epoch, steps=100):
    #initial_lrate = 0.01
    initial_lrate = 0.001
    drop = 0.96
    epochs_drop = 8
    lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop, math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return lrate

sgd = SGD(lr=initial_lrate, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)

lr_sc = LearningRateScheduler(decay, verbose=1)
# print(images_train.shape, Y_train.shape, images_test.shape, Y_valid.shape)
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[1, 0.3, 0.3], optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[1, 0.3, 0.3], optimizer=adam, metrics=['mae', 'acc','accuracy',metrics.mae, metrics.categorical_accuracy])

history = model.fit(images_train, [Y_train, Y_train, Y_train], validation_data=(images_test, [Y_valid, Y_valid, Y_valid]), epochs=epochs, batch_size=256, callbacks=[lr_sc])
```

Comment: Sir, I have attached now.